# Isometric embedding of standard simplex

Tags: isometry, simplex

The standard $n$-simplex  is the subset of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$  given by

$\Delta^n = \left\{(t_0,\dots,t_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}~\big|~\sum_{i = 0}^n t_i = 1 \text{ and } t_i \ge 0 \text{ for all } i\right\}$.

Clearly, it is actually an $n$-dimensional object. I wish to find an isometric embedding of $\Delta^n$ into a subset of $\mathbb R^n$. I might have overlooked something, and this might be trivial, but after quite some trying I still haven't been able to come up with something. Could someone help me further with this?

Comment: The $n$-simplex lives in $\mathbb R^n$. You choose $n+1$ points in $\mathbb R^n$. In the standard $n$-simplex, the point $t_0$ is $\bf 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that yours simplex spans an $n$ dimensional affine subspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which after translating it by the vector $(\frac{-1}{n+1},\dots,\frac{-1}{n+1})$, becomes a proper $n$-dimensional subspace. Now take a linear isometry from this $n$ dimensional subspace, equipped with the induced Euclidean metric, to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric, and your simplex has isometrically been transformed to $\mathbb{R}^n$: first by translation (which is clearly an isometry), and then by another isometry. I leave it to you to come up with a concrete isometry.

Comment: OK, so indeed our simplex is equal to p + V, where V = < v_1 , ... , v_n > and  where p is the vector with 1/(n+1) in every component, and v_i = ( 0 , ... , 0 , 1 , 0 , ... , -1 ) where the 1 is in the i'th spot. Now to find an isometry between V and IR^n, I think we must find an orthonormal basis of V. I know we could use Gram-Schmidt for that, but applying that formula, it seems to get very ugly... So is there another way to proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any resource about it, so I built the transformation from scratch and I want to share it.
The first part of the problem is to create $d+1$ equidistant points in $\mathbb R^d$.
The second is to use these points to define the isometry explicitly.

**Equidistant points on hyperspheres**

We proceed by induction. The goal at each iteration $k$ is to produce $k+1$ equidistant vectors $v_1,...,v_{k+1}$ lying on the surface of the unit ball embedded in $\mathbb R^k$, or in other words, on the $(k-1)$-sphere. Once $k=d$, we are done.

For $k=1$, we just take $v_1=-1$ and $v_2=1$.
Now suppose that $u_1, ..., u_{k} \in \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$ are equidistant.
Let $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be the result of scaling $u_i$ by $\frac{\sqrt{k^2-1}}{k} < 1$ and prepending to it the value $-1/k$.
And define $v_{k+1} \in \mathbb R^k$ as $[1, 0,...,0 ]^T$.
Then, $v_1, ..., v_{k} \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ are equidistant.

The following code follows this construction.
The image below shows the output (blue points) for $d=1$, $d=2$ and $d=3$.
All the pairwise distances are equal and equal to $s_d = \frac{\sqrt{2 (d+1)}}{d}$.

```
def simplex_vertices_in_d_dimensions(d:int):
    # The columns of V are the vertices of the d-dimensional simplex
    assert d > 0
    V = np.array([[-1, 1]])
    k = 2
    while k <= d:
        V_i = [([-1/k, *(np.sqrt(k**2-1)/k*u)]) for u in V.T]
        v_k = [1, *np.zeros(k-1)]
        V = np.array([v_k, *V_i]).T
        k += 1
    return V

# Equivalent one-liner recursive code: 
f = lambda d: np.array([[-1], [1]] if d<=1 else [[1, *[0]*(d-1)], *[([-1/d, *((d**2-1)**.5/d*u)]) for u in f(d-1).T]]).T
```

[image: simplices]

Notice that this matrix can be rotated arbitrarily, e.g. by using a holder transformation, and the result will still be a set of equidistant column vectors. Same if we permutate the columns. So, their order and orientation with respect to the cartesian coordinates does not have any particular meaning.

**Isometry**

Let's first adjust the scale.
I chose a sphere of radius 1, but you can choose the radius freely by multiplying the vectors with any constant.
In particular, if you scale by $\sqrt{\frac{d}{d+1}}$, the side length matches that of the standard simplex ($\sqrt{2}$), and we will obtain an isometry.
That said, let $u_i = \sqrt{\frac{d}{d+1}} v_i$.
Also, denote the simplex centroid as $\mu = (1/(d+1)) [1,1,...,1]^T \in \mathbb R^{d+1}$.

The isometries are

- $f: \mathbb R^{d+1} \to \mathbb R^d$ given by $f(x) = Ux = \sum u_i x_i$.
- $g: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^{d+1}$ given by $g(x) = \mu + U^T x$.

$f$ and $g$ are pseudo inverses of each other.